# check whether the function is launched javascript

Tags: javascript, function, append

is there any idea how I can check whether it is already added this script on the page.

```
function init(){

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = 'setTimeout(function(){ alert("test msg") }, 10000);';
document.body.appendChild(script);

}
```

**NOTE:**
 I want you to run one function until after it no longer runs.

Comment: even eval() is better than that, why not just just put the code inside script.text inside init() ?

Comment: Script works great. I want you to run one function until after it no longer runs.

Comment: _"I want you to run one function until after it no longer runs."_ - I don't understand what you mean by this. _Every_ function that you call will run until it stops running. (And I agree with dandavis: creating a script element and putting a string of JS in it seems like a way over-complicated way of doing what `eval()` would do for you, and if you have a hard-coded string of JS there wouldn't be any point in `eval()` _or_ a script element, just include that code directly in `init()`.)

Comment: *"is there any idea how I can check whether it is already added this script on the page"* give the script an id, and search for that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confused in the title you ask for a solution if the function is called and in you message you ask for a solution to check if the script exists already on the page. So I solved both.

**1) know when the script has completed loading and started running your script:**

```
function init(callback){
  var script   = document.createElement("script");
  script.type  = "text/javascript";
  script.text  = 'setTimeout(function(){ alert("test msg") }, 10000);';
  script.onload = callback;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

init(function(e){
  console.log('script loaded.',e);
});
```

**2) check if the script was already added to the dom**

```
function init(){
  var script   = document.createElement("script");
  script.type  = "text/javascript";
  script.text  = 'setTimeout(function(){ alert("test msg") }, 10000);';
  var checkExistance = document.scripts.filter(function(v){ return v.isEqualNode(script) });
  var exists = checkExistance.length>0;
  if(!exists) document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

**3) combine them if you want...** The callback won't be called if the script exists already since the file starts loading as soon as it's added to the DOM.

```
function init(callback){
  var script   = document.createElement("script");
  script.type  = "text/javascript";
  script.text  = 'setTimeout(function(){ alert("test msg") }, 10000);';
  script.onload = callback;
  var checkExistance = document.scripts.filter(function(v){ return v.isEqualNode(script) });
  var exists = checkExistance.length>0;
  if(!exists) document.body.appendChild(script);
}

init(function(e){
  console.log('script loaded.',e);
});
```